# Random order shuffle cv::Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there no function in `OpenCV` to randomly shuffle a matrx (ordered by rows)?

Input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 2 3
```

cv::randShuffle function only seems to randomly order the elements in the entire array
I'm using the newer C++ API

Comment: opencv is a great matrix manipulation library, but don't have any method for this extreme case.

Comment: It sucks that such trivial matrix manipulation methods are missing. From a guy coming from Python and MATLAB/OCTAVE background, these missing features are irritating.

Answer (score 8):

Code to shuffle the rows of a matrix:

```
cv::Mat shuffleRows(const cv::Mat &matrix)
{
  std::vector <int> seeds;
  for (int cont = 0; cont < matrix.rows; cont++)
    seeds.push_back(cont);

  cv::randShuffle(seeds);

  cv::Mat output;
  for (int cont = 0; cont < matrix.rows; cont++)
    output.push_back(matrix.row(seeds[cont]));

  return output;
}
```

Comment: The snippet does what is required but the `patternMatrix` variable is a typo and causes a compile time error and thus should be changed to `matrix`.