# Shuffle rows of image matrix using OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a *"Features"* matrix of type `Mat` with 20 rows and a column, and I have inserted values in it.

Now I want to shuffle the rows of matrix. Is there any method for shuffling rows or [a guide on how to do this in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152473/7482098)?

```
int rows = 20;
int cols = 1;
int index = 0;
Mat Features = new Mat(rows, cols, CvType.CV_64F);

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    if (i < 10)
        Features.put(i, 0, responseA[i]);
    if (i >= 10) {
        Features.put(i, 0, responseB[index]);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this compiles, but I literally ported that C++ code to Java.

```
import org.opencv.core.Core; // randShuffle is located here.

public static Mat shuffleRows(Mat matrix) {
    List<Integer> seeds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int cont = 0; cont < matrix.rows(); cont++) {
        seeds.add(cont);
    }

    Core.randShuffle(seeds);

    Mat output = new Mat();
    for (int cont = 0; cont < matrix.rows(); cont++) {
        output.push_back(matrix.row(seeds.get(cont)));
    }
    return output;
}
```

I am sure you can debug this easily. I will try compiling this shortly.